# Sort Ascending and Descending in a List

Tags: scala, collections

I have a List which has attributes (StarRating, Price) like the below in Scala:

```
ListBuffer(RatingAndPriceDataset(3.5,200), RatingAndPriceDataset(4.5,500),RatingAndPriceDataset(3.5,100), RatingAndPriceDataset(3.0,100))
```

My Sort Priority Order is :
First Sort on the basis of Star rating (descending) and then pick three lowest prices. So in the above example , I get the list as :

```
RatingAndPriceDataset(4.5,500),RatingAndPriceDataset(3.5,100), RatingAndPriceDataset(3.5,200)
```

as can be seen the star rating is the one which comes as higher Priority in sort. I tried a few things but failed to do the sort. If i sort on the basis of a star rating then Price, it fails to keep the priority order.

What I get from a calling a method is a list like this (as above). The list will have some data like below (example):

```
StarRating Price
3.5         200
4.5         100
4.5         1000
5.0         900
3.0         1000
3.0         100


**Expected result:**

StarRating Price
5.0         900
4.5         100
4.5         1000
```

Comment: When you pick three lowest prices, how did you include `PriceDataset(4.5, 500)` ? Am I missing something?

Comment: @911DidBush I am failing to do a nested or priority sort. So if I sort on basis of Star Rating followed by a sort on prices, I dont get the results as expected. Does it help?

Comment: @ganesshkumar: I have improved upon the description. So my Sort priority order is Star Rating and then Prices. hope it helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the data in the table you've provided (which is different than the data in your code):

```
val input = ListBuffer(RatingAndPriceDataset(3.5,200), RatingAndPriceDataset(4.5,100),RatingAndPriceDataset(4.5,1000), RatingAndPriceDataset(5.0, 900), RatingAndPriceDataset(3.0, 1000), RatingAndPriceDataset(3.0, 100))
val output = input.sortBy(x => (-x.StarRating, x.Price)).take(3) // By using `-` in front of `x.StarRating` we're getting descending order of sorting

println(output) // ListBuffer(RatingAndPriceDataset(5.0,900), RatingAndPriceDataset(4.5,100), RatingAndPriceDataset(4.5,1000))
```